# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP' - MA

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to get all of my inventory movements into either a 2015 or 2016 bucket. In my From Select part of the query, I get it to work but it gives me 2 lines for each item with a qty in 2015 and 0 in 2016 on the first line and a 0 in 2015 and a qty in 2016 on the second line. So I thought I could then query the select statement and group to get one line for each item. But I am getting an "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'" error. Can someone get me going in the right direction? The error occurs on the second Group By outside the From clause. Thanks.

```
SELECT [Item]
    ,[Item Desc]
    ,sum[2015 Usage]
    ,sum[2016 Usage]

FROM (SELECT 
          mtm.[item] 'Item'
          ,im.[description] 'Item Desc'
          ,case when year(convert(varchar(10), convert(date,mtm.[trans_date],1),101))='2015' then sum(mtm.[qty]) else 0 end '2015 Usage'
          ,case when year(convert(varchar(10), convert(date,mtm.[trans_date],1),101))='2016' then sum(mtm.[qty]) else 0 end '2016 Usage'

  FROM [ITEC_App].[dbo].[matltran_mst] mtm, [ITEC_App].[dbo].[item_mst] im

  WHERE
    mtm.[item] = im.[item]
    and
    mtm.[trans_type] NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'M', 'N', 'R')
    and
    mtm.[ref_type] NOT IN ('P')

  GROUP BY
    mtm.[item]
    ,im.[description]
    ,year(convert(varchar(10), convert(date,mtm.[trans_date],1),101)))

GROUP BY
    [Item]
    ,[Item Desc]
```

Comment: You need an alias name for your subquery

Comment: @juergend is right. add an "x" after the three closing brackets and before the last group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery is like this:

```
  (
  SELECT . . .
  GROUP BY
    mtm.[item]
    ,im.[description]
    ,year(convert(varchar(10), convert(date,mtm.[trans_date],1),101))
 )
```

In SQL Server, all subqueries require a table alias.  So, you just need to add one:

```
  (
  SELECT . . .
  GROUP BY
    mtm.[item]
    ,im.[description]
    ,year(convert(varchar(10), convert(date,mtm.[trans_date],1),101))
 ) i
```

Comment: In SQL Server? Which DB's *don't* require an alias?

Comment: Thank you! I did have an alias but had an ORDER BY issue and took it out thinking something else!

Comment: @Bohemian . . . Oracle for one.